# Interstitial Tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

The [interstitial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interstitial) tag is described as

> full screen iAd advertisements introduced with iOS 4.3, implemented by
>   the ADInterstitialAd class, and available only for iPad

However, a number of interstitial questions are tagged with android, and it appears that is [valid](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/advanced). I don't know anything about the topic, so I would not be able to properly edit the tag description.